# IOS 6 Maps Crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6-maps

I keep getting this crash on IOS 6 but I am not sure what is wrong.  Does anyone know what it means?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x00000001
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3bcab0d8 CFRetain + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3bd424ee __CFSetStandardRetainKey + 50
2   VectorKit                       0x3840e97c -[VKAnimation _stopAnimation:] + 36
3   VectorKit                       0x383d841c -[VKAnimation onTimerFired:] + 48
4   VectorKit                       0x383d8240 -[VKMainLoop displayTimerFired:] + 352
5   QuartzCore                      0x3664377c             CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 156
6   QuartzCore                      0x366436d4 CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 60
7   IOMobileFramebuffer             0x3c497fd4 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 152
8   IOKit                           0x35a965aa IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 190
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3bd35888 __CFMachPortPerform + 116
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3bd403e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3bd40386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3bd3f20a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3bcb2238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3bcb20c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
15  GraphicsServices                0x33eae336 GSEventRunModal + 70
16  UIKit                           0x3be33284 UIApplicationMain + 1116
17  App Name                        0x000dcb88 main (main.m:14)
18  App Name                        0x000dcb54 start + 36
```

The application is using the MKMapkit in IOS 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an internal bug. [Report this to Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com/).

You may be able to use the Simulator's "Reset Content" thing (in the app/iOS Simulator menu) to clear out caches if this is happening in the Simulator.

Comment: I did file a bug report but I found the exact problem and a work around. The problem was that I was setting [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:NO]; as the mapView was transitioning from being in the background to foreground.  I ended up setting the above line of code in the mapView delegate - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is caused by accessing a released object from within or soon after VectorKit's stopAnimation: method is called.  I'm not familiar with VectorKit, so you might look in that method or what looks to be the onTimerFired: delegate callback.

Good luck.

Tim

Comment: Thanks for the response, but all of these APIs in the crash log such as VectorKit are from Apple.  I dont have any control over them.